# Fresh install 14.04 and my /home folder appears as separate media but it is in the right place in gparted

Tags: system-installation, mount, gparted, home-directory, partitioning

After totally wrecking my system to the point where I couldn't even access the recovery mode from grub, I reinstalled ubuntu 14.04 LTS. As I was still having issues when I didn't reformat the / partition, I reformatted it this time.

I can see my old /home directory, it is appearing along the side and I can even access the files, I can't copy them as I don't have enough space (I presume in the / part of my setup)

Here is a picture of my gparted:sda7 is my /home partition

[image: gparted]

And a picture showing the location of my old /home where all my files are

[image: screenshot of filesystem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## These are the steps to get back your `/home` partition when you install Ubuntu again.

1. This time choose "**something else**" as the type of install.
2. Format `sda5` as `ext4` and select mount point `/` from the menu.
3. **Do not format** `sda7` but choose `ext4` and mount point `/home`.
4. **Use the same username** you had used before and you should get back
   your original home.

*Note to other readers:* This answer assumes Ubuntu was originally installed in `sda5` and the `/home` folder was in its own partition, `sda7`. The default installation of Ubuntu does not put `/home` in a separate partition, as it is in this case.

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked perfectly.